# Hibernate automatically appends LIMIT ? to query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using  native query with lot of joins and UNION.

For example sample query:

```
Select A.*, B.*, C.*,D.*
from A,B,C,D
where
<some  conditions>
UNION
Select Select A.*, B.*, C.*,D.*
from A,B,C,D
where 
<some conditions>
```

Spring Boot code:

```
@Query(value = "native sql with joins and uinions",nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Object[]> getPaginatedObjects( Pageable pageable);
```

Above code works well and have paginated results.

Now added some filter to above query.
To add filter, used query like below mentioned query:

```
Select * AS (
Select A.*, B.*, C.*,D.*
from A,B,C,D
where
<some  conditions>
UNION
Select Select A.*, B.*, C.*,D.*
from A,B,C,D
where 
<some conditions>) AS T1
where T1.name =:name
```

Spring Boot code:

```
@Query(value = "native sql with joins and uinions",nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Object[]> getFilteredPaginatedObjects(@Param("name") name, Pageable pageable);
```

Above query with filter executed well in DBeaver with PostgresSQL.
But in Spring application it failed.

Reason :Hibernate appended `LIMIT ?` to the end of query due to which query failed.

Surprisingly, if I use `List<Object[]>` instead of `Page<Object[]>` as return type then Hibernate does not append `LIMIT ?` to end of query.

Any solution for same?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am facing similar issue and it is appending TOP(?) in my query

Comment: @manishbansal
No, I did not.
But instead of running query from application, I converted query to DB view, which solved my problem.